# mvc3 .net selectList height changes when 'input-validation-error' class applied via JQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

A simple example:

Date Of Birth (DOB) validation - 3 Select Lists:

1st List - days of month (1-31)
2nd List - months of year (Jan-Dec)
3rd List - year (1940 - 1989)

Lose focus of any of these Select Lists and Javascript function valids the DOB.

If DOB is invalid i.e. 31 Feb 1977, class `input-validation-error` is applied to the 3 Select Lists using addClass method.

If valid, class `input-validation-error` is removed from 3 Select Lists.

It seems that the `input-validation-error` is changing the height of the select Lists.

Is there a way to stop this, as I've tried adding a height to the class, but this doesn't help.

Comment: This is a CSS problem. Could you post the default CSS for your `select`, and the `input-validation-error` class.

Answer (score 1):

Load up the page in Firefox and Inspect the element in question with FireBug. Determine what css attribute is changing the height of the element when `input-validation-error` is applied. Then fix based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've decided to implement the JQuery datepicker plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the unobstrusive validation with MVC3. Just move the **ValidationMessageFor** into a different element than the select lists, this way the css for the selectlist will not change. 
You can override/tweak the validation(from behaviour to the style) by changing **$.validator** settings.
[Have a look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3)